# Who was this girl by Lucy in special episode 10.5?

Tags: elfen-lied

In special episode 10.5 of Elfen Lied anime, there was a scene where Lucy was together with a girl in a school. Who was that girl? A friend? And why did she want to protect her? I thought Lucy hated all humans and wanted to kill them!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

She is [Aiko Takada](http://elfen-lied.wikia.com/wiki/Aiko_Takada).

Five years after murdering Kouta's family, Lucy (or Kaede as her original name was) went around killing and infecting humans. Aiko Takada was responsible for inadvertently stopping Kaede from going on another rampage when she was accidentally hit by a soccer ball.

Aiko is the second girl after [the unnamed Orphanage Girl](http://elfen-lied.wikia.com/wiki/Orphanage_Girl) who befriended Kaede. In the anime, when Kaede revealed her horns to Aiko, Aiko found them cool, like how Kouta did back then. She is also a pivotal point in Kaede's/Lucy's life as

> Kurama shot Aiko by mistake when she tried to protect Kaede. Kaede then agreed to go with Kurama to the Diclonius Research Institute because he promised that Aiko could be saved. Later in the facility, he reported to her that Aiko died, leading to Kaede/Lucy hating Kurama for breaking his words and planning to kill all his loved ones while leaving him alive like what he did to her with Aiko (as Kaede/Lucy considers Aiko a loved one of hers).